# Array Filter with custom requirement and data manipulation

Tags: javascript, arrays, node.js, sails.js

```
const data = [{
    employee: 70,
    month: 0,
    year: 2017,
    id: 3,
    createdAt: '2017-09-15T09:42:37.000Z',
    updatedAt: '2017-09-15T09:42:37.000Z',
    organization: 41,
    version: 1
},
{
    employee: 70,
    month: 4,
    year: 2017,
    id: 4,
    createdAt: '2017-09-15T09:59:28.000Z',
    updatedAt: '2017-09-15T09:59:28.000Z',
    organization: 41,
    version: 2
},
{
    employee: 70,
    month: 4,
    year: 2017,
    id: 5,
    createdAt: '2017-09-15T10:00:35.000Z',
    updatedAt: '2017-09-15T10:00:35.000Z',
    organization: 41,
    version: 3
},
{
    employee: 70,
    month: 4,
    year: 2017,
    id: 6,
    createdAt: '2017-09-15T10:01:18.000Z',
    updatedAt: '2017-09-15T10:01:18.000Z',
    organization: 41,
    version: 4
},
{
    employee: 70,
    month: 4,
    year: 2017,
    id: 7,
    createdAt: '2017-09-15T10:07:11.000Z',
    updatedAt: '2017-09-15T10:07:11.000Z',
    organization: 41,
    version: 5
},
{
    employee: 70,
    month: 4,
    year: 2017,
    id: 8,
    createdAt: '2017-09-15T10:40:11.000Z',
    updatedAt: '2017-09-15T10:40:11.000Z',
    organization: 41,
    version: 6
},
{
    employee: 70,
    month: 4,
    year: 2017,
    id: 9,
    createdAt: '2017-09-15T10:40:58.000Z',
    updatedAt: '2017-09-15T10:40:58.000Z',
    organization: 41,
    version: 7
}, {
    employee: 70,
    month: 7,
    year: 2017,
    id: 10,
    createdAt: '2017-09-15T10:40:58.000Z',
    updatedAt: '2017-09-15T10:40:58.000Z',
    organization: 41,
    version: 6
}, {
    employee: 70,
    month: 7,
    year: 2017,
    id: 11,
    createdAt: '2017-09-15T10:40:58.000Z',
    updatedAt: '2017-09-15T10:40:58.000Z',
    organization: 41,
    version: 7
}];
```

---

```
const currentMonth = // 0, 11
```

Here i need to make an algorithm to get the details from the array,

I want to get the details from array as per the required month number.

1. If the month number matches with the record present in Array, return it, and if there are multiple records of that month then it should return the month details by looking the highest value of version, suppose in the above array for the month 7 there are 2 records with version 6 and 7, so what i want is the object with highest version 7.

   There are 2 records for month 7, so i will get

   `{
       employee: 70,
       month: 7,
       year: 2017,
       id: 11,
       createdAt: '2017-09-15T10:40:58.000Z',
       updatedAt: '2017-09-15T10:40:58.000Z',
       organization: 41,
       version: 7 // <<==== highest version
   }`
2. If the month number provided by user doesn't exists then it should look at the closet lowest month nearer to it, and provide the object with the highest version, But if there are more objects with lowest month number then it should take the data with highest version

   Suppose i want the record for month 5 or 6, but in the array there is no record for that month so i will look for the closet lowest month which is 4, there are muliple records for month 4 so, i will filter i will want to get the object with the highest version id

   which is

   `{
       employee: 70,
       month: 4,
       year: 2017,
       id: 9,
       createdAt: '2017-09-15T10:40:58.000Z',
       updatedAt: '2017-09-15T10:40:58.000Z',
       organization: 41,
       version: 7 // <<======highest version
     }`
3. [Based on rules here](https://gist.github.com/parwat08/58726651e83401ac331a4c020948fe77), if the month number provided doesn't exist and there are no records in earlier months, provide the object with the highest version from the month closest to the month number provided.

What i have tried so far is here.

This work looks pretty simple, but i think i am making it more complex..
Any Kind of help is much **Appreciated**.

```
const getLastEmployeeMonthVersion = data.filter(function (emp, index) {
    if (emp.month < currentMonth) {
        return _.inRange(currentMonth, data[index].month, data[data.length - 1].month) ? emp : emp
    }
});

employeeVersionForMonth = [...getLastEmployeeMonthVersion];
const getGroupByEmployee = employeeVersionForMonth.length && _.groupBy(employeeVersionForMonth, (v) => v.employee);
const employeeKeys = Object.keys(getGroupByEmployee);
let latestEmployeeVersion = [];

employeeKeys.forEach(emp => {
    const maxVersionId = _.maxBy(getGroupByEmployee[emp], (value) => value.version);
    latestEmployeeVersion.push(maxVersionId);
})

console.log(latestEmployeeVersion)
```

Comment: need large time to solve this

Comment: take time, it's an algorithm

Comment: no, i means it is project level requirement needs much time to solve. i will answer this question shortly

Comment: yes, it a custom requirement for a specific project, this takes time

Comment: in case month value not found, then which month will be returned? high value or low value?

Comment: low value will be returned, it's provided in case 2

Comment: Please a look on answer

Comment: did you verified the cases? I guess it has issues

Comment: which case has issue?

Comment: i did not consider ordering. only filtering

Comment: I guess 2nd case isn't working, it's doing just opposite, instead of lowest closet it's providing the highest closet

Comment: i updated the answer after your comment, pls copy again

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do you mean something like this?

```js
const data = [{
  employee: 70,
  month: 0,
  year: 2017,
  id: 3,
  createdAt: '2017-09-15T09:42:37.000Z',
  updatedAt: '2017-09-15T09:42:37.000Z',
  organization: 41,
  version: 1
}, {
  employee: 70,
  month: 4,
  year: 2017,
  id: 4,
  createdAt: '2017-09-15T09:59:28.000Z',
  updatedAt: '2017-09-15T09:59:28.000Z',
  organization: 41,
  version: 2
}, {
  employee: 70,
  month: 4,
  year: 2017,
  id: 5,
  createdAt: '2017-09-15T10:00:35.000Z',
  updatedAt: '2017-09-15T10:00:35.000Z',
  organization: 41,
  version: 3
}, {
  employee: 70,
  month: 4,
  year: 2017,
  id: 6,
  createdAt: '2017-09-15T10:01:18.000Z',
  updatedAt: '2017-09-15T10:01:18.000Z',
  organization: 41,
  version: 4
}, {
  employee: 70,
  month: 4,
  year: 2017,
  id: 7,
  createdAt: '2017-09-15T10:07:11.000Z',
  updatedAt: '2017-09-15T10:07:11.000Z',
  organization: 41,
  version: 5
}, {
  employee: 70,
  month: 4,
  year: 2017,
  id: 8,
  createdAt: '2017-09-15T10:40:11.000Z',
  updatedAt: '2017-09-15T10:40:11.000Z',
  organization: 41,
  version: 6
}, {
  employee: 70,
  month: 4,
  year: 2017,
  id: 9,
  createdAt: '2017-09-15T10:40:58.000Z',
  updatedAt: '2017-09-15T10:40:58.000Z',
  organization: 41,
  version: 7
}, {
  employee: 70,
  month: 7,
  year: 2017,
  id: 10,
  createdAt: '2017-09-15T10:40:58.000Z',
  updatedAt: '2017-09-15T10:40:58.000Z',
  organization: 41,
  version: 6
}, {
  employee: 70,
  month: 7,
  year: 2017,
  id: 11,
  createdAt: '2017-09-15T10:40:58.000Z',
  updatedAt: '2017-09-15T10:40:58.000Z',
  organization: 41,
  version: 7
}];

const currentMonth = 7;
const monthLookup = data.reduce((prev, record) => {
  return record.month > prev && record.month <= currentMonth ? record.month : prev;
}, 0);
const record = data.filter((record) => record.month === monthLookup).reduce((prev, current) => {
 return prev.version > current.version ? prev : current;
});

console.log(record);
```

**Update**
(adding the [3rd rule](https://gist.github.com/parwat08/58726651e83401ac331a4c020948fe77))

```js
const data = [{
  employee: 70,
  month: 2,
  year: 2017,
  id: 3,
  createdAt: '2017-09-15T09:42:37.000Z',
  updatedAt: '2017-09-15T09:42:37.000Z',
  organization: 41,
  version: 1
}, {
  employee: 70,
  month: 4,
  year: 2017,
  id: 4,
  createdAt: '2017-09-15T09:59:28.000Z',
  updatedAt: '2017-09-15T09:59:28.000Z',
  organization: 41,
  version: 2
}, {
  employee: 70,
  month: 4,
  year: 2017,
  id: 5,
  createdAt: '2017-09-15T10:00:35.000Z',
  updatedAt: '2017-09-15T10:00:35.000Z',
  organization: 41,
  version: 3
}, {
  employee: 70,
  month: 4,
  year: 2017,
  id: 6,
  createdAt: '2017-09-15T10:01:18.000Z',
  updatedAt: '2017-09-15T10:01:18.000Z',
  organization: 41,
  version: 4
}, {
  employee: 70,
  month: 4,
  year: 2017,
  id: 7,
  createdAt: '2017-09-15T10:07:11.000Z',
  updatedAt: '2017-09-15T10:07:11.000Z',
  organization: 41,
  version: 5
}, {
  employee: 70,
  month: 4,
  year: 2017,
  id: 8,
  createdAt: '2017-09-15T10:40:11.000Z',
  updatedAt: '2017-09-15T10:40:11.000Z',
  organization: 41,
  version: 6
}, {
  employee: 70,
  month: 4,
  year: 2017,
  id: 9,
  createdAt: '2017-09-15T10:40:58.000Z',
  updatedAt: '2017-09-15T10:40:58.000Z',
  organization: 41,
  version: 7
}, {
  employee: 70,
  month: 7,
  year: 2017,
  id: 10,
  createdAt: '2017-09-15T10:40:58.000Z',
  updatedAt: '2017-09-15T10:40:58.000Z',
  organization: 41,
  version: 6
}, {
  employee: 70,
  month: 7,
  year: 2017,
  id: 11,
  createdAt: '2017-09-15T10:40:58.000Z',
  updatedAt: '2017-09-15T10:40:58.000Z',
  organization: 41,
  version: 7
}];

function getRecord(month) {
  // Check if a record exists in the current or earlier months.
  const existsInCurrentOrEarlierMonth = data.some((record) => record.month <= month);
  const monthLookup = existsInCurrentOrEarlierMonth
    // Get the max month number if a record exists in the current or earlier months.
    ? Math.max.apply(null, data.reduce((earlierMonths, record) => {
      if (record.month <= month) {
        earlierMonths.push(record.month);
      }

      return earlierMonths;
    }, []))
    // Get the min month number if no records exist in the current or earlier months.
    : Math.min.apply(null, data.reduce((laterMonths, record) => {
      if (record.month > month) {
        laterMonths.push(record.month);
      }

      return laterMonths;
    }, []));

  // Filter the data with the month lookup and return the record with the highest version.
  return data.filter((record) => record.month === monthLookup).reduce((prev, current) => {
    return current.version > prev.version ? current : prev;
  });
}

console.log('Month 1 (should get month 2\'s record):', getRecord(1));
console.log('Month 7 (should get month 7\'s record):', getRecord(7));
console.log('Month 6 (should get month 4\'s record):', getRecord(6));
console.log('Month 8 (should get month 7\'s record):', getRecord(8));
```

Comment: Hey bro, i forgot to mention 1 more case will you please help me to sort out this. https://gist.github.com/parwat08/58726651e83401ac331a4c020948fe77

Comment: @p0k8_ updated your question and my answer to accommodate the third rule.

Answer (score 1):

just Call following function get result as per your requirement

```
function findMonthRecords(month, recur)
{
    var ret_records = [];

    for (i in data)
    {
        var record = data[i];

        if (record["month"] == month)
        {
            ret_records.push(record)
        }
    }   

    if (ret_records.length == 0 && recur)
    {
        for (var a = month - 1; a >= 0; a--) 
        {
            ret_records = findMonthRecords(a, false)

            if (ret_records.length > 0)
            {
                return ret_records;
            }   
        }

        for (var a = month + 1; a < 12; a++) 
        {
            ret_records = findMonthRecords(a, false)
            console.log(a);
            console.log(ret_records);
            if (ret_records.length > 0)
            {
                return ret_records;
            }   
        }   
    }   

    return ret_records;
}


console.log(findMonthRecords(2, true));
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is another way to to implement that algorithm.

**1. `filter` array with `o.month <= currentMonth` that will list all records having month is less than current month.**

**2. `orderBy` with `month` and then `version`.**

**3. `head` first record from `ordered` list that will be your record.**

```
var result= _.head(
  _.orderBy(
    _.filter(data,
      function(o) {
        return o.month <= currentMonth;
      }), ['month', 'version'], ['desc', 'desc']));
```

```js
const data = [{
  employee: 70,
  month: 0,
  year: 2017,
  id: 3,
  createdAt: '2017-09-15T09:42:37.000Z',
  updatedAt: '2017-09-15T09:42:37.000Z',
  organization: 41,
  version: 1
}, {
  employee: 70,
  month: 4,
  year: 2017,
  id: 4,
  createdAt: '2017-09-15T09:59:28.000Z',
  updatedAt: '2017-09-15T09:59:28.000Z',
  organization: 41,
  version: 2
}, {
  employee: 70,
  month: 4,
  year: 2017,
  id: 5,
  createdAt: '2017-09-15T10:00:35.000Z',
  updatedAt: '2017-09-15T10:00:35.000Z',
  organization: 41,
  version: 3
}, {
  employee: 70,
  month: 4,
  year: 2017,
  id: 6,
  createdAt: '2017-09-15T10:01:18.000Z',
  updatedAt: '2017-09-15T10:01:18.000Z',
  organization: 41,
  version: 4
}, {
  employee: 70,
  month: 4,
  year: 2017,
  id: 7,
  createdAt: '2017-09-15T10:07:11.000Z',
  updatedAt: '2017-09-15T10:07:11.000Z',
  organization: 41,
  version: 5
}, {
  employee: 70,
  month: 4,
  year: 2017,
  id: 8,
  createdAt: '2017-09-15T10:40:11.000Z',
  updatedAt: '2017-09-15T10:40:11.000Z',
  organization: 41,
  version: 6
}, {
  employee: 70,
  month: 4,
  year: 2017,
  id: 9,
  createdAt: '2017-09-15T10:40:58.000Z',
  updatedAt: '2017-09-15T10:40:58.000Z',
  organization: 41,
  version: 7
}, {
  employee: 70,
  month: 7,
  year: 2017,
  id: 10,
  createdAt: '2017-09-15T10:40:58.000Z',
  updatedAt: '2017-09-15T10:40:58.000Z',
  organization: 41,
  version: 6
}, {
  employee: 70,
  month: 8,
  year: 2017,
  id: 11,
  createdAt: '2017-09-15T10:40:58.000Z',
  updatedAt: '2017-09-15T10:40:58.000Z',
  organization: 41,
  version: 7
}];

const currentMonth = 11;

var employeeVersionForMonth = _.head(
  _.orderBy(
    _.filter(data,
      function(o) {
        return o.month <= currentMonth;
      }), ['month', 'version'], ['desc', 'desc']));


console.log(employeeVersionForMonth);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/lodash@4.17.4/lodash.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

One walk:

```
const currentMonth = 5 // 0, 5, 10

let fMonth = -Infinity
let fVersion = -Infinity
let fIndex

for (let i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
  let item = data[i]
  if ( (item.month > fMonth && item.month <= currentMonth) ||
       (item.month === fMonth && item.version > fVersion)
     ) {
    fMonth = item.month
    fVersion = item.version
    fIndex = i
  }
}
```